Question on distributions and topology
Let $X$ and $Y$ be two topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ a function. It is well-known that continuity of $f$ implies sequentially continuity, while the reverse is in general only true if $X$ is first countable.
Now, if $U\subset\mathbb{R}^{d}$ is some open set, then one defines the space of test functions $\mathcal{D}(U)$ to be the set $C^{\infty}_{c}(U)$ equipped with the canonical LF-space topology. As a topological space, $\mathcal{D}(U)$ is not metrizable and also not first countable. The space of distributions is then usually defines to be the topological dual space
$$\mathcal{D}^{\prime}(U):=(\mathcal{D}(U))^{\prime}$$
By definition, the topological dual space is the set of linear continuous functionals.

Question: In virtually all textbooks I have seen, a distribution is defined to be a linear function $u:\mathcal{D}(U)\to\mathbb{C}$ which is sequentially continuous, i.e. $\varphi_{n}\to 0$ implies $u(\varphi_{n})\to 0$. However, then the space of distributions is not the topological dual space $(\mathcal{D}(U))^{\prime}$, but something weaker right? Since for the space $\mathcal{D}(U)$, sequentially continuity does not imply continuity. Am I missing something?


You are right in saying that $\mathcal{D}(U)$ that is not first countable. Nevertheless, it still turns out to be true that any linear functional $u:\mathcal{D}(U)\to\mathbb{C}$ is continuous if and only if it is sequentially continuous.
This is actually a consequence of the fact that $\mathcal{D}(U)$ is a LF space, i.e. the limit of Fréchet spaces. Roughly speaking the idea is the following: Let $u:\mathcal{D}(U)\to\mathbb{C}$ be linear and sequentially continuous. Since $\mathcal{D}(U)$ is a LF space, we know by definition that $u\vert_{\mathcal{D}(K)}$ is sequentially continuous for every $K\subset U$ compact. But
now, $\mathcal{D}(K)$ is metrizable and hence in particular first countable. Hence, $u\vert_{\mathcal{D}(K)}$ is continuous for every $K\subset U$ compact and hence, again by the definition of LF spaces, we conclude that $u$ is continuous also in the strong sense.
